# What is "Ambiguous regexp literal" in rubocop?

Tags: rubocop

The following code

```
expect(foo).to match /#{MyGem.config.environment_name}/
```

triggers a rubocop issue

`Warning: Ambiguous regexp literal. Parenthesize the method arguments if it's surely a regexp literal, or add a whitespace to the right of the / if it should be a division.`

Can someone explain what the issue is and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another way to fix this is to simply add parens as rubocop suggests.  Change

```
expect(foo).to match /#{MyGem.config.environment_name}/
```

to

```
expect(foo).to match(/#{MyGem.config.environment_name}/)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is complaining that at this point:

```
match /#{MyGem.config.environment_name}/
```

it is unclear whether you're dividing two numbers or passing a RegExp literal to a method call.

In this particulare case, since you're just checking for the presence of a substring within a string, it would be better to use the RSpec [#include](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/include-matcher) matcher, like so:

```
expect(foo).to include MyGem.config.environment_name
```